# How to make a ship stop moving when out of bounds?

Tags: java

I am having trouble with this code, if someone could point me in the right direction I would be very grateful. Have been stuck on it for days!!

Basically I am trying to stop the ship from moving once it reaches the boundary.
Boundary is 6 and -6.

Here is the code. Thanks :)

```
public void move (int direction) //if position exceeds 5 then playership will 
                                 //no long move in that direction.
{
    if (position > 5)
    {
        .... ?? What to write here?

    }
    else if (position < -5)
    {
        .... ?? What to write here?

    }

    position = position + direction;
    gun1.move(direction);
    gun2.move(direction);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question depends.  If you want to stop the object when it reaches its boundary, then some thing like...

```
// Move first
position = position + direction;

// Boundary check second...
if (position > 5)
{
     position = 5;
}
else if (position < -5)
{
     position = -5;
}

gun1.move(direction);
gun2.move(direction);
```

If you want to "bounce" of the walls...

```
// Move first
position = position + direction;

// Boundary check second...
if (position > 5)
{
     position = 5;
     direction *= -1
}
else if (position < -5)
{
     position = -5;
     direction *= -1
}

gun1.move(direction);
gun2.move(direction);
```

Might work - Hard to tell without any more context...

Comment: Thanks, this worked :)
And in the if statement I just put :
position = 5;
and 
position = -5;

Thanks :D

Answer (score 2):

This will keep the player at the boundary even if he tries to move out of boundary

```
public void move (int direction) //if position exceeds 5 then playership will 
                                 //no long move in that direction.
{
    if (position > 5)
    {
        position = 5;

    }
    else if (position < -5)
    {
        position = -5;

    }

    position = position + direction;
    gun1.move(direction);
    gun2.move(direction);

}
```

Comment: The only problem, is that the motion is then applied after the boundary check, meaning that the object can move out of bounds for at least one cycle...

Comment: @MadProgrammer - I think this answer is assuming that the bounds are -6 to 6 _inclusive_, whereas you're assuming _exclusive_. The OP isn't very clear about whether "reaches" is a < or ≤ relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Your method must convey the status (moved or not moved) to the calling code.
You can do this 2 ways:

1 returning status code

> ```
> public int move (int direction) //if position exceeds 5 then playership will 
>                                  //no long move in that direction.
> {
>     if (position > 5 || position <-5)
>     {
>         return -1;   //status code for no movement
>
>     }
> ```

2 throwing an exception when teh ship can't move

> ```
> public void move (int direction) throws InvalidArgumentException//if position exceeds 5 then playership will 
>                                  //no long move in that direction.
> {
>     if (position > 5 || position <-5)
>     {
>         throw new InvalidArgumentException("Cannot move!");   //status code for no movement
>
>     }
> ```

The calling code can handle the statuscode/exception how ever it sees fit.

Comment: Why?  While I won't argue the idea, what context do you have that this is how the OP's engine works?

Comment: Based on the assumption that the move() API and the calling code are not tightly coupled. And if they are they should not be. `move()` should behave in a standard way irrespective of how it is being used. Don't you agree?

Comment: As I said, I don't disagree with the idea, just how it's going to help the OP answer their question ;)